# ctypes передать массив строк в си. Ошибка: "ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1"

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

Как передать в С - функцию список слов на Python?
Если заполнять список конструкциями вроде  `arr_c[1].append(create_string_buffer(str.encode('asdffg')))` (вызов функции `lib.func(arr_c[0], len(all_arr), create_string_buffer(str.encode('test_class')), arr_c[1], create_string_buffer(str.encode('test_word')))`) функция:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" double func(char** news, unsigned n2, char* class_, char** classes, char* word)
#else
double func(char** news, unsigned n2, char* class_, char** classes, char* word)
#endif
```

Получаю ошибку

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strings = ['one', 'two', 'three']

lib = ctypes.CDLL('some_lib.dll')

array = (ctypes.c_char_p * len(strings))()
array[:] = [s.encode() for s in strings]

lib.func(array, len(strings))
```